# Pyplot Pie Chart not showing

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("fivethirtyeight")

plt.title("sub count of most popular czech youtubers")

plt.tight_layout()

slices = (2770000, 1360000, 1190000, 1120000, 918000)
labels = ("ViralBrothers", "MenT," "Gejmr", "JirkaKrál", "PedrosGames")
colors = ("white", "green", "blue", "yellow", "blue")

plt.pie(slices, labels=labels, colors=colors, wedgeprops={"edgecolor":"black"})

plt.show()
```

this is my code but when i run it, it doesn't display a pie chart. It only gives me this:

[image]

Comment: Misplaced `,` in `labels`, `"MenT," "Gejmr"` is silently joined to `"MenT,Gejmr"` making the list only 4 elements long. Voting to close for simple typo.

Comment: This code generates an error message. It usually is a good idea to read such message carefully and take appropriate action.

Answer (score -1):

There is a typo in your `labels`, where one comma is inside the quotation marks, which means `"MenT," "Gejmr"` becomes one string `"MenT,Gejmr"`. So, you need to change:

```
labels = ("ViralBrothers", "MenT," "Gejmr", "JirkaKrál", "PedrosGames")
```

to

```
labels = ("ViralBrothers", "MenT", "Gejmr", "JirkaKrál", "PedrosGames")
```